# Assembling an image from parts of others with ImageMagick (image crop syntax)

Tags: imagemagick

I have a set of source PNG images and I want to use parts of them to assemble a final PNG image. The parts are rectangular and never overlap on the destination but are of different sizes. Sometimes it is the whole of a source image and sometimes just a subsection. I want to edit the sources many times and re-assemble the final image each time, so I tried to write a script using sh and Imagemagick to do it.

I tried this

```
convert \
-size 512x512 null:\
-page +96+32 source_a.png\
-page +96+0 source_b.png[32x32+16+16]  \
-background transparent\
-layers merge\
destination.png
```

(just with two source images for illustration) 
I want all of `source_a.png` and a piece of `source_b.png`. The first is OK, but using the 'inline crop' syntax on `source_b.png` gives me an error:

```
convert: geometry does not contain image `source_b.png' @ warning/transform.c/CropImage/666.
```

The image is big enough:

```
$ identify source_b.png
source_b.png PNG 64x48 64x48+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

What's the best way to do this? I am using ImageMagick 6.9.7-0 Q16 on MacOS 10.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative might be to use `-geometry` and `-composte` to achieve the same effect:

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:white                            \
    source_a.png              -geometry +96+32 -composite \
    source_b.png[32x32+16+16] -geometry +96+0  -composite \
    result.png
```

Comment: Wow! Much cleaner solution

Answer (score 2):

PNG's will preserve the paging from inline cropping, so the addition page will through the ROI out of bounds. I imaging it'll be simpler to `-repage` the inline crop then attempting to clear previous paging & setting new page.

```sh
convert -size 512x512 null: \
        -page +96+32 source_a.png \
        \( source_b.png[32x32+16+16] -repage +96+0 \) \
        -background transparent\
        -layers merge\
        destination.png
```